# Deleting C++ classes (valgrind check)

Tags: c++, pointers, hashmap, delete-operator

I have a class HashMap, and everything seems to be working fine, however I'm having a problem with memoryleaks.

Below are my HashMap class private member variables/functions

```
   struct Node
    {
        std::string key;
        std::string value;
        Node* next;
    };

    HashFunction hashfunction;
    Node** bucketList;
    int* numberOfPairs; 
    int logins;
    int lengthOfMap;
```

And here is my default constructor:

```
 HashMap::HashMap()
    :hashfunction(hash), bucketList(bucketList = new Node*[INITIAL_BUCKET_COUNT]), numberOfPairs(numberOfPairs = new int[INITIAL_BUCKET_COUNT]),
    logins(0),lengthOfMap(INITIAL_BUCKET_COUNT)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < INITIAL_BUCKET_COUNT; i ++)
    {
        bucketList[i] = nullptr;
    }
    zeroFillArray(numberOfPairs, INITIAL_BUCKET_COUNT);
}
```

I have the bucketList pointer, pointing to an array of Nodes, and each Node points to the beginning of a linked list.

As of now, this is my destructor:

```
HashMap::~HashMap() 
{
    delete numberOfPairs;
    delete bucketList;
}
```

Do I delete EACH Node (I'll tackle this in the morning, but I wanted to ask regardless) within the list before I delete the list, or am I missing something else entirely?

Comment: Why don't you read the diagnostics that Valgrind produces and figure this out yourself?

Comment: Yes you delete each node. Pointers don't delete themselves ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HashMap::~HashMap() 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < INITIAL_BUCKET_COUNT; i ++)
    {
        Node* node  = bucketList[i];
        while( node != nullptr)
        {
            Node* next = node->next;
            delete node;
            node = next;
        }
    } 
    delete numberOfPairs;
    delete[] bucketList;
}
```

Comment: Does this delete each pointer pointing to the first Node at bucketList[i]? This seems like it will only delete the linked list without deleting the first Node pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You have manualy to delete every node from your `bucketList`. Saying manualy i mean you should go throw every node and delete it.
Like this:

```
HashMap::~HashMap() 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < INITIAL_BUCKET_COUNT; ++i)
    {
        if( bucketList[i] )
        {
            Node* first = bucketList[i];
            while( first )
            {
                Node* temp = first->next;
                delete first;
                first = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    delete[] bucketList;
    delete numberOfPairs;
}
```